# mysql print date as date(week no)

Tags: mysql, date

I have a mysql table with date column, I want to print my table in a pattern that in a same column it should print date as date(week no.) or date-week no.
e.g. 2014-06-05-Week 22 or 2014-06-05(Week 22).

Please suggest, my table looks like as below:

```
------------+-----------+-----------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+  
 date       | 2006_2007 | 2007_2008 | 2008_2009  | 2009_2010  | 2010_2011  | 2011_2012  | 2012_2013  | 2013_2014  |  
------------+-----------+-----------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+  
 2013-06-05 | 412684953 | 618821373 |  912382161 | 1152333713 | 1696469379 | 1992249499 | 2311645340 | 2525687604 |
```

Comment: Check out the [`WEEK()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_week) function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `MySQL WEEK()` returns the week number for a given date.

The argument allows the user to specify whether the week starts on Sunday or Monday and whether the return value should be in the range from 0 to 53 or from 1 to 53. If no argument is included with the function, it returns the default week format.

Syntax

```
WEEK(date[mode]);
```

Example

```
SELECT WEEK('2009-05-18',1);
```

[image]

**EDIT**

```
SELECT CONCAT('2009-05-18', '-week ', WEEK('2009-05-18',1));
```

Comment: yes that is ok but i want to print week number with date like "2014-06-05-week 22" any suggestions how can we do that ?

Comment: can you add your current search query in qustion ?

Comment: You can use the [CONCAT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) function. ```SELECT CONCAT('2009-05-18', '-week ', WEEK('2009-05-18',1)); ```